# Software to run powershell commands on remote machine

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, administrator

These are machines in different forests, different domains. I want an easy way to run simple commands in the background of their machines such as restarting print spooler.

Is there an easy way to set this up or software to help out?

Comment: What have you tried?  You can restart the print spooler with a Powershell script easily enough.

Comment: Use [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to run remote scripts ...

Comment: Do you want a fixed or open setup. Fixed (or limited) means only those things setup before can be done. Easiest is if there is a scripts (or bat) folder on the machine with appropriate files made such as restart_spooler. Then just need access rights to the share, etc.  Limit is if need to do a new thing, will need to RDP, make a new script, etc.  With being in different forests, domains this approach is the less head aches. Can still do a open (or connect to machine with powershell or RDP and do what ever you want)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be this:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <DNS NAme> -Credential Get-Credential
```

When doing this all the commands you run are run on that remote computer

Answer (score 0):

PsExec is a great suite of tools to run remote commands. I am assuming if you are an administrator, then you have administrator credentials across all domains, so you can also use powershell remoting, but you would have to enable some gpos to allow it because it is disabled by default.
Check out this link for more information on powershell remoting:
http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/